# Parsing rankings from Alexa

Tags: javascript, node.js, html-parsing

I am working on parsing the data from Alexa categories like this [one](http://www.alexa.com/topsites/category/Top/Business/E-Commerce).

My code can be found [here](http://pastie.org/8454191).

I am getting the websites' URL list and then try to get each website's ranking. The problem is that I am getting back a fine websites list (array) and a messed up ranks list (also an array but out of the expected order). My clues so far is that something is wrong regarding the node blocking feature (I use async.series to run one function at a time but it doesn't work) and the for loop definitely has a problem.

I run this from command line using "node". Any advice/help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues with your code :

1. Closure problem for scope of `i`
2. Rank insertion does not happen incremently (for me `i` goes like this `4 0 2 1 3 5 7 6 12 11 9 13 8 15 16 18 21 19 17 22 23 20 14 24 10`)

To fix this change your second function like this:

```
...
function (callback) {
    for (i = 0; i < websites.length; i++) {
        clr(i);
    };
}], function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

function clr(i){
    alexaurl = "http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/" + websites[i];
    request(alexaurl, function (error, response, body) {
        $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $('.siteInfoPage #traffic-rank-content .metricsUrl a').each(function () {
            //ranks.push($(this).text());
            ranks[i]=$(this).text();
            return false; // so it does not count the a:hover element
        });
        console.log(i);
        console.log(websites);
        console.log(ranks);
        console.log("The website " + websites[i] + " has a rank of " + ranks[i]);
    });
}
```

Comment: really appreciate your help.